# Hadoop - Restart datanode and tasktracker

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to bring down a single datanode and tasktracker, so that some new changes that i've made in my mapred-site.xml take effect, such as mapred.reduce.child.java.opts etc. How do I do that? However I don't want to bring down the whole cluster since i have active jobs running.

Also, how can that be done ensuring that the namenode does not copy the relevant data blocks of a "temporarily down" datanode onto another node

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**To stop**

You can stop the DataNodes and TaskTrackers from NameNode's hadoop bin directory.

```
./hadoop-daemon.sh stop tasktracker 
./hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode
```

So this script checks for **slaves** file in **conf** directory of hadoop to stop the DataNodes and same with the TaskTracker.

**To start**

Again this script checks for **slaves** file in **conf** directory of hadoop to start the DataNodes and TaskTrackers.

```
./hadoop-daemon.sh start tasktracker
./hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
```

Comment: i wanted to stop just 1 tasktracker/datanode combination. not the whole cluster since i had jobs running. i'll clarify my question accordingly

Comment: In that case you need to ssh into the DataNode and execute your commands.

Comment: I found `hadoop-daemon.sh` in `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin`

Answer (score 10):

In Hadoop 2.7.2, tasktracker is long gone, to manually restart services out on slaves:

```
yarn-daemon.sh stop nodemanager
hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode
hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
```

Comment: Glad you mentioned 2.7.2 - perhaps Hadoop questions should be tagged with a version?

Answer (score 4):

Ssh into the datanode/tasktracker machine and cd into the bin directory of hadoop.

Invoke

`./hadoop-daemon.sh stop tasktracker`

`./hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode`

`./hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode`

`./hadoop-daemon.sh start tasktracker`

I'm not sure if restarting the tasktracker is required for the changes in mapred-site.xml to take effect. Please leave a comment so that i can correct my answer if needed

Comment: This answer helped me - some of my data nodes were dead (not responding to dfsadmin -report) and SSHing into the offending node and doing this helped bring them back online.