# Unable to load large file to HDFS on Spark cluster master node

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, hdfs

I have fired up a Spark Cluster on Amazon EC2 containing 1 master node and 2 servant nodes that have 2.7gb of memory each

However when I tried to put a file of 3 gb on to the HDFS through the code below

```
/root/ephemeral-hdfs/bin/hadoop fs -put /root/spark/2GB.bin 2GB.bin
```

it returns the error, "/user/root/2GB.bin could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1". fyi, I am able to upload files of smaller size but not when it exceeds a certain size (about 2.2 gb).

If the file exceeds the memory size of a node, wouldn't it will be split by Hadoop to the other node?

Comment: what do you mean by "have 2.7gb of memory each"? do you refer to RAM or hard-disk?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Summary of my understanding of the issue you are facing:

1) Total HDFS free size is 5.32 GB

2) HDFS free size on each node is 2.6GB

Note: You have bad blocks (4 Blocks with corrupt replicas)

The following Q&A mentions similar issues:
[Hadoop put command throws - could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27147096/5088142)

In that case, running JPS showed that the datanode are down.

Those Q&A suggest a way to restart the data-node:

[What is best way to start and stop hadoop ecosystem, with command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569423/what-is-best-way-to-start-and-stop-hadoop-ecosystem-with-command-line)
[Hadoop - Restart datanode and tasktracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208696/hadoop-restart-datanode-and-tasktracker)

Please try to restart your data-node, and let us know if it solved the problem.

---

When using HDFS - you have one shared file system

i.e. all nodes share the same file system

From your description - the current free space on the HDFS is about 2.2GB , while you tries to put there 3GB.

Execute the following command to get the HDFS free size:

```
hdfs dfs -df -h

hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

or (for older versions of HDFS)

```
hadoop fs -df -h

hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

Comment: when it says "DFS Remaining: 5713575936 (5.32 GB)" on the Master Node and on the 2 data nodes it says "DFS Remaining: 2856787968(2.66 GB)" are they referring to diskspace or RAM?

Comment: can you please provide the command you executed and its output?

Comment: command execute: ./hadoop dfsadmin -report, output: Configured Capacity: 8443527168 (7.86 GB)
Present Capacity: 5713715200 (5.32 GB)
DFS Remaining: 5713575936 (5.32 GB)
DFS Used: 139264 (136 KB)
DFS Used%: 0%
Under replicated blocks: 4
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 2 (2 total, 0 dead)

Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 4221763584 (3.93 GB)
DFS Used: 69632 (68 KB)
Non DFS Used: 1364905984 (1.27 GB)
DFS Remaining: 2856787968(2.66 GB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 67.67%